# What's the benefit of defining a topology on a set?

Tags: general-topology

Say, for example we pick $R$ and define the order topology on it. The one good thing is that by classifying subsets as open or closed according to order topology, we satisfy the definition of topology. But what good does it do? Please explain with and without the use of metrics.

Comment: **Please** use actual words. Unless you're paying by the letter, in which case, find a better service provider.

Comment: Topology spaces are more general spaces and extensions of metric spaces. We can do more things with this configuration.

Comment: I think OP might want to know why *order* topologies are useful. OP might already agree that topological spaces in general are useful (though perhaps not, I am not sure). Edit: I guess the title of OP's question actually disagrees with what I just said.

Comment: @par Exactly, i have read everywhere that they are generalizations of metric spaces but how do I see that?

Comment: @Drake: every metric space $(X,d)$ is a topological space by defining the open sets as $\tau = \{ G \subset X \colon B_r(x) \subset G \text{ for some } x\in X \text{ and } r >0 \}$, where $B_r(x)$ is the ball of radius $r$ centred at $x$ defined using the metric $d$. Make sure to check that $\tau$ is a topology by applying the definitions. However, not every topological space is metrizable.

Comment: @par maybe you mean x is in G?

Comment: It doesn't really matter. If $x\in X$ and $B_r(x)\subset G$, then $x\in G$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have topology, you have a notion of continuity. This continuity can limit the sorts of functions you consider in useful ways: for example, many functional equations (solving something like $f(x^2) = xf(x)$, where $f : \Bbb R\to\Bbb R$) is greatly simplified once you demand that $f$ is continuous. The axiom of choice can allow many horrible strange functions you really wouldn't normally consider or care about, and by only looking at continuous ones (which have nice properties), you simplify your problem and simplify the answer.

Another good example comes from [representation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory). If you're familiar with a representation of a group (a homomorphism from $G\to GL_n(K)$ for some field $K$, unless you want to get fancy), you might know that these objects let you use linear algebra techniques to study the group in question. Sometimes, your group will have a natural topology, like if $G$ is a [Lie group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group) or [profinite group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profinite_group), and in these cases, it is often the representations which are continuous or smooth (giving $K$ a suitable topology) which play a central role in classifying how these groups behave as opposed to the larger class of all representations.

It might be good to note that usually (or at least often) when you put a topology on a set, it's somehow given to you from the construction of the set or the problem you're trying to solve. If you cared about something like absolute values or valuations, it might make more sense to equip $\Bbb R$ with the order topology and ask for the absolute values to be continuous with respect to this topology as opposed to the standard topology on $\Bbb R$, but if you're concerned with Euclidean space, you'll probably give $\Bbb R$ the usual metric topology.

To answer the question you asked in the comments above, you can think of a topology as giving you a notion of when points are close, like a metric does, but in a more loose way. The notion of continuity from real analysis uses epsilons and deltas to say that "$f$ is continuous if when you have two points that are close together, they map to points that are close together." The topological definition of continuity says something like this as well, if you think of open sets as telling you when points are close to each other (two points are "close" if there are "a lot" of open sets containing both of them). Of course, this is a somewhat loose analogy, so take it with a nicely sized grain of salt.

Comment: does inclusion of the whole set in topology mean that every element has all the other points in its neighbourhood(large epsilon) whereas the other elements of topology tell about their smaller neighborhoods?

Comment: @Drake That's a decent way to interpret it, and corresponds roughly to the last paragraph I added.

Comment: Thanks alot. Extremely happy!!!